# AR Drone 2.0 SDK for Android on Windows

Tags: windows, android-studio, sdk, ar.drone

I have a Parrot AR Drone 2.0. I want to install the SDK but documentation file which is [here](http://ardrone2.parrot.com/developer-zone/) is not good enough. How can i set up the AR Drone 2.0 SDK for Android Studio on Windows?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: No, I could not find anything, sadly.